# Symfony2 form type attribute in view

Tags: php, html, symfony

I using form type in symfony 2.8.x.
I need form attribute text in view.

form type:

```
$builder->add(  'category_id', ChoiceType::class,
            array(  'label'=>'Category',
                    'constraints'=>array(   new Regex(array("pattern"=>"'([^0-9]*)$'si", 
                                                            "message"=>"Required field!"))
                    ),
                    'choices'=>$categoriesRepo->getAllActive(),
                    'choices_as_values'=>true,
                    'choice_label' => 'getName',
                    'choice_value' => 'getId',
                    'attr'=>array(  'class'=>'form-control',
                                    'help'=>'Help message.',
                    )));
```

In view:

```
<?php echo $view->render("XXXBundle:XXX:form_element.html.php", array('form'=>$templateForm['category_id']))?>
```

form_element.html.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $view['form']->label($form, null, array('required'=>false, 'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-md-3 control-label'))) ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php echo $view['form']->widget($form, array('attr'=>array('help'=>false))) ?>
        <span class="help-block error"><?php echo $view['form']->errors($form) ?></span>
        <span class="help-block"> HELP_MESSAGE </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need "help" attribute to **HELP_MESSAGE** in view.
There is a solution to this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are the first Symfony user I've ever seen who renders PHP files instead of twig. Congratulations.

The real business part of your code you haven't posted, so it's hard to give a definitive answer, but somewhere at the bottom of your controller's action function there will be a call to `$this->render('XXXBundle:XXX:template.html.php');`

The 'Symfony way' is to pass the help message in that:

```
$help_message = 'My Help Message';
$this->render('XXXBundle:XXX:template.html.php', array('help_message' => $help_message));
```

In your template file:

```
<?php echo($view['help_message']);?>
```

Comment: Thanx for answer!
We using php instead twig. (My colleagues and lead developer want php instead twig and I don't like it too)
Your answer it's correct, but I don't write "form text" to controller.

I need help message in Form Type class.